# While I compile, I get 'Command Not Found' Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to compile a C file to Rolling Spider. But I got error.

```
Drone: Trying to pack autogenerated code using PackEmbeddedCode...
C-files are being packed...
C-files packed and ready to be built! 
Drone: Autogenerated code using PackEmbeddedCode packed!
Drone: Trying to build code...
/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o Drone_Compensator.o ../Drone_Compensator.c -lm
make: /opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Here is a code 'DroneUploadEmbeddedCode.sh'

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. change folder to where this script is
cd `dirname $0`
SCRIPTPATH=$(pwd)

# 1.2 Exit the script if a command fails
set -e

# 2. Pack autogenerated c-code
echo "Drone: Trying to pack autogenerated code using PackEmbeddedCode..."
cd utils/
./PackEmbeddedCode
cd ..
echo "Drone: Autogenerated code using PackEmbeddedCode packed!"

# 3. Build code
echo "Drone: Trying to build code..."
cd ../trunk/embcode/build_arm
make
cd $SCRIPTPATH
echo "Drone: Code built!"

# 4. ftp into the drone and upload the shared library
echo "Drone: Trying to upload shared library..."

echo "> Drone: FTP into the drone"
/usr/bin/expect <<SCRIPT
set timeout -1;
spawn ftp 192.168.1.1;
expect "(192.168.1.1:$USER):";
send "\r";
expect "ftp>";
send "put ../DroneExchange/librsedu.so librsedu.so\r";
expect "ftp>";
send "exit\r";
expect eof
SCRIPT

echo "Drone: Shared library uploaded!"
```

Also, This is 'Makefile' code

```
CC=/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

all:
    $(CC) -c -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o Drone_Compensator.o ../Drone_Compensator.c -lm
    #$(CC) -c -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o Drone_Compensator_capi.o ../Drone_Compensator_capi.c -lm
    $(CC) -c -DDELOS -DDELOS_EDU -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o rsedu_control.o ../rsedu_control.c  -lm
    $(CC) -c -DDELOS -DDELOS_EDU -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o rsedu_vis_helpers.o ../rsedu_vis_helpers.c  -lm
    $(CC) -c -DDELOS -DDELOS_EDU -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o rsedu_vis.o ../rsedu_vis.c  -lm
    $(CC) -c -DDELOS -DDELOS_EDU -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o rsedu_of.o ../rsedu_of.c  -lm
    $(CC) -c -fPIC  -Wall -Werror -o rtGetInf.o ../rtGetInf.c
    $(CC) -c -fPIC  -Wall -Werror -o rtGetNaN.o ../rtGetNaN.c  
    $(CC) -c -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o rt_nonfinite.o ../rt_nonfinite.c
    $(CC) -c -fPIC -Wall -Werror -DDEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE=4600 -o rt_logging.o ../rt_logging.c 
    #$(CC) -c -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o rt_logging_mmi.o ../rt_logging_mmi.c
    #$(CC) -c -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o rtw_modelmap_utils.o ../rtw_modelmap_utils.c

    #
    $(CC) rsedu_control.o  rsedu_vis_helpers.o rsedu_vis.o rsedu_of.o Drone_Compensator.o rtGetInf.o rtGetNaN.o rt_nonfinite.o rt_logging.o -lm -DDELOS -DDELOS_EDU -fPIC -shared -o ../../../DroneExchange/librsedu.so -I./
```

So, I tried to follow the files. I found 'arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc' file on correct folder. Also, I could see on terminal.

```
> ~/Downloads/RollingSpiderEdu-master/MIT_MatlabToolbox/libs/gcc-arm-Toolchain/opt/arm-2012.03/bin$
> ls arm-none-linux-gnueabi-addr2line  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdbtui
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar         arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gprof
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as         arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++filt    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-cpp        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-elfedit    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-readelf
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-size
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.6.3  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-sprite
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcov       arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strings
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip
```

Here is file property

```
 file -L arm-none-linux-gnuea
bi-gcc
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped
```

This is my computer

```
 ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=504637666875a5d526ef51acfe601c99efc99114, stripped
```

What is the problem here? Is this problem because of difference between 32 bit and 64 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the line in the Makefile

`CC=`

with the correct path to the compiler you want to use.

From your post, it seems like this is

`~/Downloads/RollingSpiderEdu-master/MIT_MatlabToolbox/libs/gcc-arm-Toolchain/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`